# is this the right way to use react hooks?

Tags: javascript

I am currently following this [example](https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout/blob/master/test/examples/6-dynamic-add-remove.jsx) but I am not sure if i can use it this way

```
import _ from "lodash";

...

let [widget, setWidgetList] = useState([]);

onRemoveItem(i) {
    console.log("removing", i);
    setWidgetList(_.reject(widget, { i: i }));
}
```

Below code is from the example

```
 onRemoveItem(i) {
    console.log("removing", i);
    this.setState({ items: _.reject(this.state.items, { i: i }) });
  }
```

Comment: This is [.reject](https://lodash.com/docs/#reject`), a lodash method.

Comment: The question is unrelated to reactjs and typescript. The code is pure JavaScript with Lodash.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing that which is TypeScript specific. It's all valid JS.

`_` is a variable name

`.reject` accesses a property of the value (an object) of that variable.

```js
const _ = {
  reject: function() {
    console.log("called");
  }
};

_.reject();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all javascript, `_.reject` is from a lib called lodash, you could see it's imported at the beginning of the file.

By the way, `_.reject` in the your example could be achieved by the same built-in array method `filter`

```
onRemoveItem(i) {
    console.log("removing", i);
    this.setState({ items: this.state.items.filter(item => item.i !== i) });
}
```